# Making labels for pointer in BIDS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I have a gauge which has a scale with several pointers. What I would like to do is to make the value of the pointer and its title appear below them (the pointers, I mean). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to find it. It was buried in gauge properties -> Scales -> Custom labels.

Comment: Where do you see custom labels? Because I do not have such a tab in the gauge properties...