# SSRS/BIDS - How to add text/label to a pointer?

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I'm trying to add a label or text to a pointer in a Gauge. I've searched on the web but I'm unable to find out how to display the numerical value associated with the pointer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Note: I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896582/making-labels-for-pointer-in-bids) but I can't find the option(s) mentioned in the answer by the OP of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property was hard to find.

It's in the gauge's property's Scales (in the property sheet, not the pop up window).

[image]

Comment: +1 for the images! They honestly couldn't have put it in a more confusing location. Thanks a lot... I was trying to position it by using offsets.